# can't find css, images and js static files in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources

my servlet-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aitrich.learnware.web" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!-- Maps '/' requests to the 'home' view -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/js/libs/**" location="/resources/js/libs/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/img/**" location="/resources/img/" />

    <!-- Internationalization support -->

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="locale/messages" />
    </bean>

    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <!-- THYMELEAF-SPECIFIC ARTIFACTS -->
    <!-- TemplateResolver <- TemplateEngine <- ViewResolver -->
    <!-- **************************************************************** -->

    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <!-- These lines configure the dialects to use with Thymeleaf -->
        <property name="dialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.dialect.SpringStandardDialect" />
                <bean class="nz.net.ultraq.web.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And i access the image using thymeleaf like

```
<img src="../../resources/img/cancel.png" th:attr="src=@{resources/img/cancel.png}, title=#{background}, alt=#{background}" />
```

But nothing is showing..!

Comment: did you try to access using `/resources/img/cancel.png` or `resources/img/cancel.png`?

Comment: What is the path to the image (resources) within your war file?

Comment: webapp/resources/img.cancel.png

Comment: +1 your configuration in servlet-context.xml helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have java project and your resources/img/** or resources/css/**  folder comes under WebContent  you can access the your resources like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/styleV.css"    
 type="text/css" />
```

and similar way for images and js file.

Or second approach is you can add following mapping in web.xml for your servlet.

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

and access the css as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css">
```

Comment: thnx due its working ..
and one more how can i access swf file using swf object???

Answer (score 1):

Try add to web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and my css/js/img located - webapp/js/, webapp/img/, webapp/css/

Answer (score 0):

I just found on Linux that I have to remove the starting "/" in my resource mapping! 
see here

```
<!--    NOTE the location does not have a starting /!!!! -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/" />
```

boy did this cause me a lot of frustration.  All the examples have the / prefix for location.  It works great now by calling c:url pattern example below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="<c:url value="/resources/css/coreStyle.css" />" type="text/css">
```