# Spring Boot Web Static resources

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

According to the docs Spring Boot registers `src/main/resources/static`, `src/main/resources/public`, `src/main/resources/resources`, etc. for static resources locations.

I got

```
src/main/resources
    -static
        -js
           -stomp.js
```

and in the html(placed in templates folder):

```
<script type="text/javascript"  th:src="@{/js/stomp.js}"></script>
```

but I got 404 for the script(`GET http://localhost:8080/js/stomp.js 404 (Not Found)` ). What I do wrong?

I also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../static/js/stomp.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/js/stomp.js"></script>
```

with the same result.

My mvc configuration(just one view-controller):

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller"})
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addViewController("/sock").setViewName("/index");
    }
}
```

and i got

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

in the POM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312034/cant-find-css-images-and-js-static-files-in-spring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explicit declaration of `@EnableWebMvc` disables Spring Boot's autoconfiguration for Web MVC.

Either remove it from your `WebMvcConfig` to enable autoconfiguration, or add resource handlers for static content manually in `addResourceHandlers()` if you don't want to enable autoconfiguration.